# Debug CTE with variables?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

Many times I want to look check the result of a certain query within a `CTE` with a @variable without having to alter the whole thing by adding `select * from cte` at the end.

An example is something like this:

```
declare @From date
declare @To date
declare @city varchar(20)
declare @st varchar(5)

// Lots of code that sets all the @variables

;with cteSales as
(
    select * from MyTable 
    where 
    From = @From and To = @To and 
    salesman = @salesman and city = @city and st = @st
) 
//HERE GOES A LONG QUERY THAT USES cteSales
```

The only way I know to debug the query in the CTE is to 1) replace the variables with values and execute the query or 2) comment everything after `cteSales` and add `select * from cteSales`.

The latter is less uncomfortable, but both require changing lots of things from the original code.

Is it possible to debug a `select` stament in a `cte` without using any of the above two options?

Comment: How about just copying what you need to another query window and debug that way?

Comment: If this is a CTE you use a lot you could create a copy of it as a table valued function/stored procedure. That way you could simply call the function/procedure to debug it. With the stored procedure option you could add debug in to it for the purpose of selecting subsets of the data to drill down on what you generally need to find out.

Comment: I always use option 2, `comment everything after and select * from CTE`.

Comment: I always run the query outside of the cte and sometimes print(@variable); before the query or cte, if it's a complex calculation getting the value. for recursive cte's I go to the level I desire to see the values of and select * from the cte section in question.

Comment: Why would you ever need to replace the variables with values?   I can see how you might want to replace complicated code that sets the variables with a simple `SET @var1 = 'x'`, but what could you possibly learn from replacing the variable with a hard-coded value in the CTE code?

Comment: @TabAlleman, well if the query inside  the `CTE` is `select * from table where date = @yesterday` I can replace @yesterday so it looks like `select * from table where date = cast(DATEADD(dd, -1, getdate()) as date)`

Comment: yeah, I figured that out myself a minute ago.  : )  And then you can just highlight the CTE query and execute it.   Gotcha.   See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option, using your code example, would be to do this:

```
declare @From date
declare @To date
declare @city varchar(20)
declare @st varchar(5)

// Lots of code that sets all the @variables

--;with cteSales as   --comment these two lines out for testing
--(
    select * from MyTable 
    where 
    From = @From and To = @To and 
    salesman = @salesman and city = @city and st = @st  --highlight the code up to here and execute
) 
//HERE GOES A LONG QUERY THAT USES cteSales
```

EDIT in response to:

> I was thinking that the IDE had some obscure hidden feature that would
>   let me view the results of a cte without having to alter the whole
>   query

In that case, the answer is no.   There is nothing like that in the IDE.

Comment: Thanks, but I was thinking that the IDE had some obscure hidden feature that would let me view the results of a cte without having to alter the whole query.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the very long query into a cte as well, then at the bottom all you have to do is comment out one line.

```
;with cteSales as
(
    select * from MyTable 
    where 
    From = @From and To = @To and 
    salesman = @salesman and city = @city and st = @st
) 
, cteVeryLongQuery as (
    //HERE GOES A LONG QUERY THAT USES cteSales
)
SELECT * FROM cteVeryLongQuery
-- SELECT * FROM cteSales -- Uncomment this for debugging `cteSales` and comment out the line above.
```

Finally, if you're using SQL Management Studio, use the shortcuts `Ctrl+K+C` to comment out lines and `Ctrl+K+U` to uncomment them.

Comment: Thanks, but I was thinking that the IDE had some obscure hidden feature that would let me view the results of a cte without having to alter the whole query.